# $http angular doesn't work despite CORS enabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, cors

Before I delve into angular, I made a clean test on my server to check if my CORS is enabled. Using this script.

```
    var xhr     = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var param   = 'name=mrA';
    xhr.open('POST','http://api.otamarket.local/api/cors.json',true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
        console.log('response: ' + this.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhr.send(param);
```

It works just fine as you can see.

[image]

But when I used angular via $http

```
var http = "//api.otamarket.local/api/cors.json";
return $http.post(http,credentials);
```

I get this error.

[image]

Here is the header response:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://api.otamarket.local/api/cors.json
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed

Request Headers view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.otamarket.local
Origin:http://otakuket.local
Referer:http://otakuket.local/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36

Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 28 Nov 2014 03:47:31 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.11
```

Here is where I enabled CORS

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\aldri_000\SkyDrive\Program  Experiment\websites\api.otamarket.local\public"
    ServerName api.otamarket.local
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
<Directory "C:\Users\aldri_000\SkyDrive\Program Experiment\websites\api.otamarket.local">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the endpoint:

```
public function post_cors()
{
   $rsp            = array();
   $rsp['rsp']     = 'CORS Work';
   return $this->response($rsp);
}
```

As you can see, I had enabled CORS in the vhost of my apache server. It works via XHR and I am puzzled as to why it doesn't work here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see, content-type is not set properly when using $http call. try adding headers property to your $http call like this,

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: url,
data: $.param({fkey: "key"}),
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

})

Comment: Question: Why does the data property needs to be under the $.param ?

Comment: that is just a sample code. you can use a valid json string in that place.

Comment: I passed an object, but it seems that the server doesn't recognize it.

Comment: i have never tried passing an object. but, i guess angular has got httprequest interceptor, that will convert your object into a valid json string and send it on wire. what server you are using? the server must be having a handler for POST methods. Either put debug statements in the method to get the post method body (or) see in browser developer tools, the http request's post body...

Answer (score 0):

Your error Message clearly states that the error is not associated with CORS.

It's returning 405, which means that the request method doesn't matches with the one that is been defined on the server.

As you see in your headers, Your request method is OPTIONS, whereas i assume that your server method has been designed for POST.

Cross Check if you have any HTTP interceptors written or if some piece of code is changing your request header.

Also, since you're retrieving data, why not use Get Request ..

Try this snippet instead :

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '//api.otamarket.local/api/cors.json'}).
        success(function(data, status) {
          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.data = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
      });
```

Comment: Angular preflights $http requests with HTTP.OPTIONS first. Based on the response, his server side implementation needs to respond to OPTIONS requests with allowed request types for $http to work.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Preflights POST/DELETE/GET/PUT requests with an OPTIONS request first. Upon a successful response from the server stating what methods are allowed by the server, angular then makes the PUT/POST/XXX request. Your server isn't responding with allowed request types when it receives OPTIONS from Angular.

Comment: Is there anything I can do in the server end to allow it?

Comment: Depends on the technology you're using on your server side implementation. Most every server side language that supports http requests has some way to handle OPTIONS requests. What language do you plan to implement on your server side and we can probably point you in the direction of good docs.

Comment: for Apache? How to allow it?

Comment: Apache is your web server software. What is your API written in? I see the url: http://api.otamarket.local/api
Is that a NodeJS api? Or a php API? or a ????

Comment: Oh, it's PHP api. I added the API function on the OP.